# PHP object interactions

Tags: php, object

I'm having issues with two objects I have created. Once I have called one I'm struggling to call the other. Let me write some of the code from the two objects to show what I mean.  What I have so far works great.

```
class User {
private $userdata = array();

public function __construct(){      
}

public function set($var, $value) {
    $this->userdata[$var] = $value; 
}

public function get($var) {
      if(isset($this->userdata[$var])){
         return $this->userdata[$var];
      }
    return NULL;
    }
}
```

Then I have my user service class:

```
class UserService {
private $db;
private $error;
private $fields = array();


    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = new Database();

    }

            public function updateUser(){
                  //some update query
            }




            public function getCurrentUser($fields) {   

    $query = sprintf("SELECT ".$this->fields." FROM User WHERE IDUser=%s", 
$this->db->GetSQLValueString($_SESSION['MM_Username'], "int"));
        $result = $this->db->query($query);

        if($result && $this->db->num_rows($result) > 0) {

            //create new user class
            $user = new User();
            $row = $this->db->fetch_assoc($result);

            //set rows as object
            foreach($row as $key => $value){
                $user->set($key, $value);   

                             return $user;
            }
                     }
             }

}
```

On the page when I'm calling a user I run this code:

```
$um = new UserService();
$userfields = "*";  
$user = $um->getCurrentUser($userfields);
```

So I now have instantiated my User() class by calling `getCurrentUser()` I'm struggling to see how I now call the `updateUser()` on $user since the $user var is part of the User class and not the `userService` class.

Comment: A few problems I can spot: firstly, you are using a legacy constructor approach, use `__construct()` instead. The indentation of `getCurrentUser` is in a bit of a state - can you fix that in your original code, and ideally fix it in the question too? It makes it so much easier for your readers (the attributes and methods should all be one indentation level in). Lastly that method is labelled as a getter, but does not return anything (i.e. there is no `return` statement at the end).

Comment: @halfer thanks I just copied some bits wrong.  It not I'm struggling to get the user data.  I'm struggling to call any method on the $user that belongs in the userService class as $user is in the User class.  I hope that makes more sense

Comment: Well, you seem to have accepted an answer now, but if in future you can take care to supply only well-formatted code, we'll not struggle to read it! Experienced programmers really do wince when they see inconsistent indenting, and it can put them off answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `updateUser` is defined in your `UserService` class, the best way to make it act on a particular `User` instance would be to pass it in as a parameter.

For example, change the declaration to

```
public function updateUser(User $user) {

}
```

and call it like this

```
$um->updateUser($user);
```

---

If you don't want to have to do that, you could also change the `User` class to keep a reference to the service that created it. Note that this is probably bad design, as it tightly couples `User` and `UserService`, and so trades some maintainability for convenience.

```
class User {
    protected $service;
    public function __construct($service) {
        $this->service = $service;
    }
    public function update() {
        return $this->service->updateUser($this);
    }
    // ... other code you already had ...
}
```

... and then in your `getCurrentUser` function change `new User()` to `new User($this)`

Comment: I tend to recommend that there are few genuine needs for `private`, since it is probably desirable for any sub-class to have access to `$service`. Thus, imo, it should be `protected`. Nevertheless, +1

Comment: While we're at it, why not typehint the object via `public function updateUser(User $user) {`.